# C# exception when trying to invoke from a loaded assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have the following the situation at hand: 2 C# files (an executable: A.exe, and a dll: B.dll). The executable loads the assembly for B, and tries to Invoke a constructor from B (that takes a reference from a class in A).

All well, so far, it works perfectly in general usage. The problem occured when trying to run the exe from a script, using 8.3 filename paths, such as:

```
start C:\testpa~1\A.exe
```

At this moment, the loading fails with the following exception: Object of type 'A.IfaceModel' cannot be converted to type 'A.IfaceModel', on the line

```
fullIface = contrs[0].Invoke(new object[] { this, forceStartMenu });
```

As far as I can tell, by running the exe with this path, somehow the assembly information for A that is in A differs from the assembly information for A that is in B, and crashes.

I know short filenames should no longer be used, but it's a valid test-case and I was wondering if there's anything to do about it.

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried to replicate this and have not been able to (it seems to work correctly even when started via the 8.3 short name). Can you provide some code, or ideally a *compilable* minimal example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am also not able to reproduce the issue on a bare-bone project. It seems that it is related specifically to the behavior of the original project, and unfortunately, I am not at liberty to share the code. Maybe someone has actually encountered this problem before, hopefully. Anyway, thanks for trying.